# ffmpeg: add single frame to end of video as images are acquired

Tags: ffmpeg

I wish to add a frame to the end of a video just after it has been captured so I can make a timelapse video as the images are acquired.

So the idea is to take an image, use ffpmeg to make the video by adding each image just after it is aqcuired.
I've seen many questions about adding a set length of time of a logo type image or how to compile a whole bunch of single images to a video but not this.

Anyone got a good idea of what to try?

Comment: What format are the images? And do you care about file size?

Comment: how can timelapse and "as the images are acquired" work here?

Comment: @Mulvya i can choose, but normally jpg

Comment: Will you be adding one image at a time?

Comment: @rogerdpack - i intend to add an image to a video in the time between image acquisition. That makes a new video as such and then the process is repeated. So ideally not reproccessing the entire video each time

Comment: I am also trying to achieve this and am having great difficulty due to the output video being corrupt or not showing the added frames, please, if you find an answer let me know.

Comment: @rogerdpack - I've made some progress since this - it's not a perfect solution though - or indeed using ffmpeg anymore - I was trying to make a timelapse camera with a Raspberry pi originally and so I found a way to do this with OpenCV - here is some code to look at https://github.com/gchennell/RPi-PiLapse - however the files get size limited to 366Mb for some reason - not sure how to fix - I have a separate question posted now